# VB.net & LINQ - identifying date types

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, ms-access

I'm pretty new to LINQ, so it's still a little over my head.

With a few lines of VB, I'm copying data tables from an MS Access database to a SQL Server database. I'm using LINQ to identify which parts of the transferred data are strings and numbers, etc., so it will know whether to put single quotes or not.

Now I've hit a snag because some of the fields are date type fields, and I can't seem to get LINQ to recognize them as dates. Here's the simplified query string:

```
 Dim Itemarray = row.ItemArray.Select(Function(i) If(TypeOf i Is Date, "#" + i + "#", i.ToString))
```

And VS is flagging that line saying, among other things,

> "Data Type(s) of the type parameters(s) cannot be inferred from these
>   arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this
>   error."

I've also tried using the `DateAndTime` type, and it shows the same thing.  But I am not seeing any other data type that would work.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeOf` is used for objects. Use [`VarType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.vartype(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Dim Itemarray = row.ItemArray.Select(Function(i) If(VarType(i) = VariantType.Date, "#" + i + "#", i.ToString))
```

Note that I'm not familiar with VB.Net, just VBA and VB in general, so I might've missed obvious things.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm disappointed to say that it didn't work. It made a lot of sense, but just didn't recognize it as a date. The strange thing is that, while the program was stopped in the middle of this process, in the immediate console I typed '?VarType(i)' and it indicated it as a date anyway. But the code just doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Correction.... it worked when I shuffled a few things around. EDIT: I should explain that the entire line includes multiple .select functions, and I guess they need to be in a certain order. I still haven't got it  completely worked out, but I think this gives me a clue about getting it done.

Comment: Erik, I wound up taking a different approach, but still using VarType to determine how to format the resulting string. So even though I couldn't get it to work with a LINQ statement, your answer helped me understand the VarType function, so I used it in a Select Case structure. I found that I needed it for other variants than date type. Thanks! (I accepted your answer because it is no doubt right, even though I wasn't able to get it to work right for my purposes.)